# Asp.net website running on dotnet 2.0 through CAS Policy dotnet 4.0 exception

Tags: asp.net

asp.net website running on dotnet 2.0 through CAS Policy exception on one page and display its running on dotnet 4.0. Here is exception message

"This method explicitly uses CAS policy, which has been obsoleted by the .NET Framework. In order to enable CAS policy for compatibility reasons, please use the NetFx40_LegacySecurityPolicy configuration switch. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=155570 for more information."

[ScreenShot of Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsRZs.png)

While the website is targeted and build on dotnetfx 2.0. Everything on local IIS is running fine. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is pretty obvious, given the additional information in [your CodeProject copy of this question](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1169804/Asp-net-website-running-on-dotnet-through-CAS-poli): your live site is running in a .NET 4.0 AppPool.

Either change the live site to use a .NET 2.0 AppPool; or replace the obsolete calls with the .NET 4.0 equivalents; or add the configuration switch.

The link in the error message explains the second and third options:
[Code Access Security Policy Compatibility and Migration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee191568(v=vs.110).aspx)

*(Cross-posted from [CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1169804/Asp-net-website-running-on-dotnet-through-CAS-poli).)*